# Is there anyway to to "Template-like" check if there are missing or wrong values in an Object in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates

I'm receiving data from an API (one JS Object each time) and want to check if any of the values in there is missing or of the wrong datatype.
Is it possible to define something like a template:
e.g.
`{"name": String, "Housenumber: "Integer`}
and check if the actual object has the same keys and datatypes?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: That's not a programming question ... It's not a trivial task, you've to analyze the data object and the template (or store the template as ready analyzed), then compare the template analysis against the data object analysis. The analysis is done with a recursive function, which stores the object types and property types into a data structure as strings. Checking the data is still not easy, because the order of the object properties is not necessarily always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can just create an object with all the `keys` and `datatypes`. After that you can just loop over the object and check it against your data.

Be aware that you can't check the difference between `floats` and `integers` with the use of `typeof`. For that you need a custom check.

Though i suggest something like [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) for type checking since it has lots of build in functionality for it.

```js
const personInterface = {
  name: "string",
  age: "number",
};

const persons = [
  {
    name: "bob",
    age: 18,
  },
  {
    name: "karen",
    age: "50",
  }
];

for(const person of persons) {
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(personInterface)) {
    if(typeof person?.[key] === value) {
      console.log(`${person[key]} matches ${value}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`${person[key]} does not match ${value}`);
    }
  }
}
```